# How to underline the string in a string-array

Tags: android, xml, underline

I have a string-array  in strings.xml. How can I underline the string in item?

For string we do like this..

```
  <string name="clickable_string">This is a <u>clickable string</u></string>
```

I tried something like this.

```
    <string-array name="products">
        <item>this is a <u> clickable</u> string </item>
        <item> <u> clickable</u> string </item>
        <item>this is a <u> clickable</u> string </item> 
     </string-array>
```

Its not working. How can I do that?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way it will work

```
 <string-array name="description">
     <item> <Data> <![CDATA[ Check this <u>Redirect to Next Activity</u> ]]></Data> </item>
 </string-array>
```

In java Code use this :

```
    ArrayList<String> title_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] description_Array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.description);
    String categoryAndDesc = null;
    for(String cad : description_Array) {
      categoryAndDesc = cad;
      title_list.add(categoryAndDesc);
    }
    CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(categoryAndDesc);

    seperator_view.setText(strBuilder);
    seperator_view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<string name="clickable_string">This is a &lt;u&gt;clickable string&lt;/u&gt;</string>
```

(i.e) Replace the < and > with &lt; and &gt; in your *strings.xml* for HTML formatted content.

And in your code use:

```
String text = context.getString(R.string.clickable_string);
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: Thank you @Raghunath ..For string its working. I was looking solution  for string-array..

Comment: Do the same inside <item> That's all :)

Comment: No @Raghunath ..It is not working like that...tried like venky said its working but the same string is acessing..the last entry of the data...Thank you for replying  ..